# how to show axis in chart using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to make chart using **d3** library .I want to show axis in my chart .I am getting error is I add this line **.call(axisn);**..I try like that 
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/WrZavV?editors=101

I used this api http://d3js.org/

```
var data=[20,30,70,80];
var widthc=500;
var heightc=500;
var scaleLiner=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([0,widthc]);
var axisn=d3.svg.axis().scale(widthc);
var canvas=d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',widthc).attr('height',heightc).append('g').attr('transform','translate(50,0)')


canvas.selectAll('rect').data(data).enter().append('rect').attr('width',function(d){ return scaleLiner(d)}).attr('height',50).attr('y',function(d,i){ return i*100})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
var data=[20,30,70,80];
var widthc=500;
var heightc=500;
var scaleLiner=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([0,widthc]);
var axisn=d3.svg.axis().scale(scaleLiner); 
// while setting axisn, the parameter for scale should be scale instead of width
```

Second, you need to call axis to render them in svg, such as:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

More detail is available in this [tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) and this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)